# Is it possible to have a foreign key reference multiple tables in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I am designing a database schema for a ticket management system.
A part of the schema will include the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE workflow 
(
    workflow_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
);

CREATE TABLE ticket_state 
(
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES workflow(workflow_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ticket_state_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
    PRIMARY KEY (workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal)
);

CREATE TABLE project 
(
    project_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES workflow(workflow_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
);

CREATE TABLE ticket 
(
    project_id BIGINT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES project(project_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ticket_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ticket_state_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id, ticket_id)
);
```

Is it possible to add a constraint to restrict `ticket.ticket_state_ordinal` to values of `ticket_state.ticket_state_ordinal` for the `workflow_id` associated with the project referenced by `ticket.project_id`?

I tried adding a workflow_id column to `ticket` like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ticket 
(
    project_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ticket_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL, -- purely for relational consistency
    ticket_state_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id, workflow_id) 
        REFERENCES project(project_id, workflow_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal) 
        REFERENCES ticket_state(workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id, ticket_id)
);
```

in order to add the two foreign keys that should keep the values valid.

This however fails at the first foreign key due to there being no unique index on workflow_id.

I expected this to fail, but wanted to try anyways, in case postgres recognizes that the foreign key references the entire primary key, and so any additional column is guaranteed to only have 1 value to choose from.

Comment: Your issue here is exactly why you should put surrogate keys on the `ticket_state` and `ticket` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adda I ique consraint to the referenced table

Better is always to reference the primary key as this is already unique, but you can add more if the need arises

```
CREATE TABLE workflow (
    workflow_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
);

CREATE TABLE ticket_state (
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES workflow(workflow_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ticket_state_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
    PRIMARY KEY (workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal)
);

CREATE TABLE project (
    project_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES workflow(workflow_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
      , unique (workflow_id, project_id) 
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
    project_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ticket_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workflow_id BIGINT NOT NULL, -- purely for relational consistency
    ticket_state_ordinal INT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns omitted for brevity
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id, workflow_id) REFERENCES project(project_id, workflow_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal) REFERENCES ticket_state(workflow_id, ticket_state_ordinal) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id, ticket_id)
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4qJh8kBt)

Comment: While this is a working solution, I'd prefer a solution that does not put a copy of `workflow_id` from the `project` table into the `ticket` table.

But if that is not possible, this will have to do.

Comment: You tables to o ctopped, you can only reference 1 table in a foreign key , but you can add in project a foreign key for it

Comment: If you have no direkt relationship ,you can make a bridge table instead of a fpreinkey